# CSS styles are targeted properly in FF and IE but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get my drop down navigation to display properly. It does in FF and the newer versions of IE, but does not in Chrome. I think it might be related to the fact that my parent list items have unique ID's and the selector I use in my CSS for some reason doesn't target the child ul under the parent li's properly. Can someone take a look at my code for Chrome and see if they find any issues? Thank you.

CSS:

```
#nav_1348933 li#about:hover > ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:6.9em;
  left:0;
  z-index: 100;
  margin:0;
  padding-bottom:1em;   
}

#nav_1348933 li#admissions:hover > ul{
  position:absolute;
  right: 7em;
  top:6.9em;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-bottom:1em;       
}

#nav_1348933 li#academics:hover > ul{
  position:absolute;
  right: 0.25em;
  width: 480px;
  top:6.9em;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-bottom:1em;       
}

#nav_1348933 li#financial-aid:hover > ul{
  position:absolute;
  right: 15.75em;
  top:6.9em;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-bottom:1em;       
}

#nav_1348933 li#resources:hover > ul{
  position:absolute;
  right: 8.25em;
  top:6.9em;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-bottom:1em;       
}

#nav_1348933 li#donate:hover > ul{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:6.9em;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-bottom:1em;       
}

#nav_1348933 ul{
  position:relative;
  display:none;
  margin:0;
  width:31em;   
  list-style:none;
  background: url(/_images/Layout/hover-tab-body.png) repeat-y;
  z-index: 100;
  padding:0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em;  
}
```

Link to site:

http://lltc.designangler.com

Comment: @AdamBotley I tried both removing the "li" before the ID's and also putting a space between. Removing the "li" did nothing and putting a space caused even weirder issues.

Comment: pseduoclass cascade algorithms work in chrome : https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3700/css_dropdown_menu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will help quite a lot in making your menu work, is making the LI's directly under the menu display: inline-block;. This way, the menu items have actual dimensions, to which the children ul's can be positioned.

```
#nav_1348933 > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are my new best friend. =) Thank you very much. This did the trick. Been fighting with this for at least 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Update the rule `#nav_1348933 li:hover > ul` to the following:

```
#nav_1348933 li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Also, change the order of the sub `UL` with the main link.

Example:

```
<li id="about">
  <ul id="navsub_1348933_1008341">
  //SUBMENU ITEMS HERE
  </ul>
  <a href="/about/about.htm">About</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for me to change the order of the navigation like that. The menu is created dynamically. The reason I went with ID based selection for each menu is that the sub menus are wide, and some have to be positioned to the right, otherwise the menu gets cut off on the right side of the screen on the parent navigation on the right side of the page. That is why I can't use a catchall left positioning on the menus.